# Как обработать исключение - System.PlatformNotSupportedException: "System.IO.Ports is currently only supported on Windows."?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, исключения

Хочу в консольном приложении подключиться к ПЛК через переходник RS485/USB. Не доходя до прочего кода (параметры подключения, чтение и запись данных ПЛК), получаю указанное выше исключение:

```
using System.IO.Ports;

List<string> allports = SerialPort.GetPortNames().ToList(); // здесь выходит исключение
string port = allports.Last();
SerialPort serial = new SerialPort(port); // если убрать предыдущие две строчки, заменив port на "COM4", то тогда здесь выйдет исключение
```

**Основной вопрос:** как правильно обработать это исключение (отключать не хочется) ?
Изменял параметры проекта с дефолтных на: Целевая платформа - Windows; Целевая версия ОС - 7; Целевая платформа - х64. Не помогло, вернул на прежние (нет целевой платформы и Any CPU), чтобы потом под Linux опробовать работу приложения.

**Дополнительный вопрос:** на Windows строка `string port = allports.Last();` выдаёт мне через C#Interactive (тут это исключение не выходит и код работает) результат `"COM4"`. Такое наименование, как я понимаю, свойственно только для Windows. Будет ли указанный код работать на Linux, чтобы сделать мне `new SerialPort(port);` с результатом вроде `"/dev/ttyUSB0"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**По основному вопросу:** ПКМ по имени проекта в Обозревателе решений -> Управление пакетами NuGet -> в строке поиска пишем System.IO.Ports -> Установить

Как было сделано до этого (и выкидывало исключение): была добавлена "Зависимость" (также в Обозревателе решений ПКМ по "Зависимости" -> Добавить ссылку на проект) в виде скачанной библиотеки System.IO.Ports.dll

По дополнительному вопросу - ещё не проверял.

Comment: это в хвалёном C#, так трудно понять, что не хватает dll?

Comment: Не трудно, т.к. VS сразу подчёркивает строку using System.IO.Ports. Понятно, что нужна dll, но она была добавлена через Зависимости изначально, а не через NuGet пакеты. Не знаю, в чём разница этих способов добавления, но один способ выдаёт исключение, а другой - нет.